# How to exclude a transitive optional Maven system in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I need to use `compile group: 'org.apache.yetus', name: 'audience-annotations', version: '0.10.0'` in a Gradle project. However, as can be seen [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.yetus/audience-annotations/0.10.0/jar), it has a `system`-scoped `optional` dependency.

I have the following defined in my `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'jdk.tools', module 'jdk.tools'
    }

}
```

I was expecting this would take care of erasing the dependency from the dependency tree/graph.

However, it's still complaining with:

```
carlspring@carlspring:/java/opensource/gradle/possible-gradle-bug> gradle --no-daemon clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:0.10.0.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:0.10.0.
      > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/yetus/audience-annotations/0.10.0/audience-annotations-0.10.0.pom
         > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

What more do I need to do in order to really exclude this dependency, which shouldn't actually be required, as I'm building the code using a JDK (`1.8.0_144`)?

I'm using Gradle `4.2.1`, (not sure, if upgrading will be an option, unless it's a 4.x version).

I have a "Hello, World!" application illustrating this [here](https://github.com/carlspring/possible-gradle-bug).

I have the feeling this is a bug and I've filed [gradle/gradle#10058](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10058), but I might be wrong. Please, advise!

Comment: Can you tell if the parent POM for `audience-annotations` was located and downloaded correctly? That's where the version is located, at least [here](https://github.com/apache/yetus/blob/master/pom.xml). Or, maybe you have to explicitly supply a version? Maybe it needs to find the version (i.e. pass Gradle's dependency validation) before it can exclude the dependency.

Comment: I think it's downloading it properly, but it's failing to proceed, because it can't find a version for the `jdk.tools` `system`-scoped `optional` dependency.

Comment: My thought was maybe if you could make it find the version somehow, it might actually get to the exclude processing (though IMO shouldn't need the version for that). I read the bug report; thanks for opening the YETUS JIRA too. Agree that the system dependency is not a good plan. I was surprised to see it in a library like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me :

```
configurations {
      all*.exclude module : 'jdk.tools'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What version of Gradle are you trying this with?

Comment: Is your `configurations` section in the main part of the `build.gradle`, or in `allprojects`?

Comment: It is in the main part

Comment: I have the `configurations.all { exclude group: 'jdk.tools', module 'jdk.tools' }` in a gradle script which I'm importing. I have other excludes there. It doesn't complain, but it doesn't seem to be affected at all. Did you try it with the `org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:0.10.0`?

Comment: I use this to exclude some logging related dependencies from spring-boot which conflicts with confluent's avro-serializer dependencies.

Comment: I don't think this helps. Please, check my updated description.

Comment: Can you try it with the "Hello, World!" project I've provided in my updated description? Thanks!

Comment: The "Hello, World!" works. My Java version : jdk1.8.0_181.jdk and gradle : gradle-4.10.2

Comment: Thanks for trying it! Woud you mind commenting on https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10058 that this works for you in version `4.10.2`? I tried it and it worked for me with that version. It seems there were some changes between the two versions and this was fixed. I'm not sure, if we'll be able to upgrade to that version right now, but knowing that this works in newer versions is great help!